# pgina not able to authorize as per rules

Tags: windows, ldap, openldap

I have the following settings
[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdrV8.png)

and these are the authorization rules I have added

[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvksx.png)

Yet pgina is unable to correctly identify and follow the rules.
Here is the output of simulation.
[bwayne is a member of group testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7rBR.png) but it's allowed because of the default rule and not the rule specified. When I check the log, it is unable to match properly. And I have also specified it to add my user to local group but it is not doing that as well.
[img 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOEU3.png).

I believe it has got something to do with filter but I am unable to figure out what exactly. I have tried memberUid, member. Chat gpt said to try memberOf. Tried gid, gidNumber but nothing is helping.